# Interaction of BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization and CollectionChanged in multi threaded WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to develop a multi-threaded WPF application. As part of that, I am using...

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(
                            IEnumerable collection,
                            object context,
                            CollectionSynchronizationCallback synchronizationCallback)
```

... to avoid worker threads updating the `ListView` which will result in an exception.

When an `ObservableCollection` raises `CollectionChanged` on a worker thread, the above will ensure transition to the UI thread.

You can implement your own lock in `synchronizationCallback` as follows:

```
protected void synchronizationCallback(
            IEnumerable collection,
            object context,
            Action accessMethod,
            bool writeAccess)
{
    ReaderWriterLockSlim listLock = context as ReaderWriterLockSlim;

    if (writeAccess)
    {
        listLock.EnterWriteLock();

        accessMethod();

        listLock.ExitWriteLock();                

        return;
    }

    listLock.EnterReadLock();

    accessMethod();

    listLock.ExitReadLock();
}
```

but to avoid recursive locks, I found I need to exit the `ObservableCollection` lock before raising `CollectionChanged`.

```
protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Assert(!this.listLock.IsReadLockHeld);
    Debug.Assert(this.listLock.IsWriteLockHeld);

    this.listLock.ExitWriteLock();

    base.OnCollectionChanged(e);

    this.listLock.EnterWriteLock();
}
```

As such, it is possible that another worker thread enters the `ObservableCollection` before the lock is encountered in `synchronizationCallback`. Therefore, .NET Framework code, if it needs to read the `ObservableCollection`, could end up reading a different state to that notified in `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`.

However, is that a problem? My thinking is no as the `ListView` will then just be updated with later state.

Comment: See Remark 4.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a problem  - you may get a '*Collection cannot be changed during OnCollectionChanged event*' exception, as the event may not have completed before the second worker thread attempts to alter the state of the collection.